# If boolean is represented as int in the JVM, how does it correspond with Java being strongly-typed?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I read that JVM represents boolean as 4-byte (int).
My question is - Java is strongly typed - and conversion to int is not allowed.
As I understand, JVM is used to run code accordingly to Java's specs (?), so if a 3 + true written in C++ is compiled to byte-code, it is legal.

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't know what you've been reading, but a `boolean` is a `true`/`false` value and the internal storage of such a value is entirely up to the implementation of the JVM. It is not in any way equivalent to the Java `int` value. The JVM may store it as a bit, a byte, a word, a dword, or anyhow else it wants to. E.g. a single `boolean` may be a dword, but a boolean array may be bytes or bits.

Comment: Are you compiling C++ to JVM bytecode?  If the answer is yes, then ask that compiler's vendor how they deal with JVM specs for boolean

Comment: Here, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.4 , it is written that boolean are represented as 0 and 1.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak that was more of theoretic question, since not only Java can be compiled to byte-code.
Similar question, is - how to determine (or is it not needed?) whether 1 came from integer 1 or `true`

Comment: @NatanZB That doesn't say anything about the `boolean` being stored as an `int`, it just says that `true` is stored as `1`, and `false` is stored as `0`, and that any language compiler that would allow coercion of `boolean` to `int` should make the conversion like that. The *storage* can still be bit, byte, word, dword, ...

Comment: Thi is all irrelevant. The *implementation* language or ts type system doesn't have to be strongly typed. You could implement it entirely in assembly language. The *Java language* is strongly typed, courtesy of the compiler and the rules implemented by the JVM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding “JVM is used to run code accordingly to Java's specs” is wrong.

There are two distinct specifications

1. [The Java® Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) which describes the semantics and behavior of the Java programming language. It’s typically used to create software that runs in a JVM, but this is no strict requirement.
2. [The Java® Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html) describes the JavaVirtual Machine, a certain execution environment, which has been designed to be convenient as a target platform for software written in the Java programming language, but is not restricted to this use.

This is clarified right in the [JVM Spec §1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-1.html#jvms-1.2-130):

> The Java Virtual Machine knows nothing of the Java programming language, only of a particular binary format, the `class` file format. A `class` file contains Java Virtual Machine instructions (or *bytecodes*) and a symbol table, as well as other ancillary information.

So there can be arbitrary differences that have to be accommodated by Java compilers when compiling source code of the Java programming language targeting the Java Virtual Machine as execution environment.

---

That said, it is wrong to say that “JVM represents boolean as 4-byte (int)”. You have been misled by the fact, that at certain places, items of distinct types are handled by the same instructions. Especially that for *local variables*, `boolean` and `int` values are handled by the same instructions, however, the same applies to `byte`, `short`, and `char`, all five types are handled equally using the same byte code instructions.

Actually, the fact that `long` and `double` types are handled by other instructions, is a historical compromise to simplify the implementations at the time when the first JVM was designed. The type of each variable and stack entry can be inferred at every place, so it would also work with a generic instruction set without any encoded type information.

While these instructions dealing with local variables and the operand stack make no distinction between `boolean`, `byte`, `short`, `char`, and `int`, the JVM makes a distinction between all these types when it comes to method and field signatures. There, `boolean` *is* a dedicated type. In contrast, when it comes to arrays, `boolean` arrays and `byte` arrays are handled using the same instructions, which are different to the instructions dealing with `int` arrays. Still, the `boolean[]` and `byte[]` arrays itself have a distinct type.

Whether the actual storage of values of these types differs, is entirely up to the particular JVM implementation.